# Errors from older dependencies than declared?

Tags: npm, electron

In my electron-app Ive installed some Sass-Dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.2",
    ...
  },
```

But when running electron, the browser-dev-tools within the electron window throws some error:

```
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (64)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.7.2
```

The strange thing is, that in package.json the dependency **node-sass** is declared in a higher version as the error message shows.

Could that be a peer-dependency-problem?